# Upgrading sqlalchemy schema database using Flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Have my app running in production with sqlalchemy but in my new update I had to update the database schema to add a new row in a table. If I restart my web server I get an error message saying that there is not such a column.
How do I update the database schema without losing any data in production?

My run.py:

```
from myApp import create_app
from myApp.db_init import init_db


app = create_app()
init_db(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

In init_db.py I have this:

```
def init_db(app):
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called *migrating* a database. Flask-SQLAlchemy has a library to handle this called [Flask-Alembic](https://flask-alembic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Comment: Ok. That's good. I have added this library to my project:

        alembic.revision('made changes')
        alembic.upgrade()

and now I'm getting this error:

raise util.CommandError("Target database is not up to date.")